# Laravel - toJson() method not escaping quotes (") so I can't parse it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5

```
{!! Auth::user()->myClass()->get()->lists('custom_name','id')->toJson() !!}
```

returns something like

```
{"1":"Category G - George Costanza","2":"Category "ABc" - Dwayne Johnson"}
```

this rises to an error when trying to parse it with javascripts `JSON.parse`

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 ...`

Shouldn't the `toJson()` return escaped quotes as:

```
{"1":"Category G - George Costanza","2":"Category \"ABc\" - Dwayne Johnson"}
```

I hope I'm missing something basic here.

EDIT:

custom Accessor:

```
public function getCustomNameAttribute(){
        return $this->parentModel->name . ' -  ' . $this->name;
    }
```

The myClass is manyToMany relation that otherwise works fine. As far as I can tell.

Comment: Using `toJson` on a collection works just fine for me. What's going on in that `myClass` method?

Comment: Updated with code and changed example to make more sense. `parentModel` has `"` in its name.

Comment: Not really sure what's going on on your end, but all that should work just fine. I've tried setting up an accessor for a model with `return 'Some "string" ' . $this->name;` and the double quotes get escaped as expected.

Comment: Did you try to use `{{ }}` instead of `{!! !!}`?

Comment: @Laerte, yes, but that gives me all `&quot;` so it's not a valid JSON then, and I can't parse it.

Comment: I skipped this one and just hope to remember not to use quotes in parent names. I lost an hour at this at least, maybe two, and such a tiny glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `{!! Auth::user()->myClass()->get()->lists('custom_name','id')->toJson() !!}`

that's using `{!! !!}` or `{{ }}` use `<?= ?>`

they enclose the resulting json in extra double quotes `""` instead of single quotes `''` therefore `parseJSON` won't be able to parse it.

therefore you could use this

`var javascript_var = $.parseJSON('<?= Auth::user()->myClass()->get()->pluck('custom_name','id')->toJson() ?>');`

that is using the short hand echo function of php `<?= ?>`

Comment: Please make your answer clear so that it can be understandable by other users